# Sencha Touch - Multiple instance of one panel generated on adding to viewport

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have generated fieldset (textboxes,selectfield etc) inside panel. After login done i display this panel using bellow code from my controller.js

```
Ext.Viewport.add({xtype: 'IntakePanel'});
Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({xtype: 'IntakePanel'});
```

But after this if i try to inspect i can found two panels are there

[image: As shown in bellow image]

And due to this if i try to access fields of panel i got array with length 2/4 etc.
I try to remove it using

```
  Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);
```

but doesn't help much.

Please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: which version of sencha touch are you using ? 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the framework is reinstantiating your component because when you pass only the xtype, it can't know you are trying to reference the same instance as before. try adding an id to your instance and instead of passing an xtype to setActiveItem, give it the result of a component query.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#yourCompoId'):
```

Comment: how can i use Ext.ComponentQuery.query to setactive panel ?? can you please give me any example ??